# iMacro code needed for refresh page until it loads completely?

Tags: javascript

I'm using imacros for chrome.I need to login in a webpage but the problem is the webpage is sometime loading may be it doesn't open sometime so i want imacros to reload the webpage until it loads completely with maximum retry .Can anybody give me the code please thnx in advance...

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

```
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 120
```

This line of code will set page loading time to 120 seconds

```
REFRESH
```

This one will refresh the page.

And here you will find other useful command lines. http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference